# How to use json object in d3.js reusable chart pattern

Tags: json, d3.js

I am working on a reusable bar chart example and had it working with a simple array. However, since I have added more data through a json object I am not able to get this to work any more. The additional data I am including is a dimension and labels all necessary to add to the visualization. I am using d3.v3.js.

- To clarify, this is for a horizontal bar chart not a vertical (column) chart.

Here is a simplified json object:

```
var module_1_data = [
    {"dimension1": "snow is fun",
     "dim1_label": "campaign",
     "metric1": 15,
     "met1_label": "clicks"
    }, 
    {"dimension1": "painting for art", 
     "dim1_label": "campaign",
     "metric1": 22,
     "met1_label": "clicks"
    }
];
```

Here is the call to the bar_chart function from my html page:

> bar_chart("220","400",module_1_data,"1")();

Here is the reusable_bar_chart.js: https://gist.github.com/analyticsPierce/5144641

Here is the html for my complete example page containing the complete json objects: https://gist.github.com/analyticsPierce/5154104

I also added this example page to my site here: http://www.marketingscience.co/example_d3/bar_chart_example.html

The error messages I get back are:

> Error: Invalid value for  attribute width="NaN" >

I can console.log the width in the bar_chart function and I can console.log the values in metric1 through data[0].metric1. However, when I include the anonymous function it seems to fail and I am not able to console.log d.

I appreciate any help or suggestions.

Comment: Use the browser's debugging tools: break on exceptions, and then look at the stack when you get your error, validating your assumptions about variable values at each level.

Comment: from the answers so far, I have eliminated the second error. However, I am still stuck on retrieving the metric1 data from the json objects to use in the var x = d3.scale.linear. It seems like this data needs to be an array and I am not sure how to transform.

Comment: as an update, I got the errors to stop. However, the chart does not display as it should. It should look like a horizontal bar chart and right now most of the rect elements are stacked on top of each other.

Comment: Looks like you fixed it. Nice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, check out lines 15 and 39.  On each, you call a method which takes two parameters:

1. **an array of data**
2. *(optional) a key method*

In both cases, you are missing the data array.

`/* line 15 */ d3.max(MISSING_DATA_ARRAY, function(d, i) { return d.metric1; } )`

and

`/* line 38/39 */ bar_chart.selectAll("text").data(MISSING_DATA_ARRAY, function(d) { return d.metric1; })`

the fix on line 39 will solve your "metric1 is undefined" error

---

Second, back when you were using an array of numerics, lines 35 worked great.  Now that you are using objects, you run into trouble because `x` is a function which returns the correct width based on the data point passed as an argument.  When the argument is a number, it's cool, when it is an object, the function does not know how to do the math.

So, on line 35, replace:

`.attr("width", x)` with `.attr("width", function(d){ return x(d.metric1); })`

the combination of these two fixes will solve your width="NaN" error.

Comment: Can you help me understand what the MISSING_DATA_ARRAY is? is this an empty array or where I should be populating the data I need from metric1?

Comment: Ok, I think i see what you are getting at. The edits you suggested were the right direction but not completely fix the problem. I do not have erros but the chart does not display the rect elements corrctly.

Comment: I ended up writing a javascript function to parse the array of json objects into different simple arrays and variables in the reusable_chart_pattern.js. Thanks for your help. Completed example is at the link in my question.

Answer (score 2):

You have two main problems. 
1. You are aren't supplying an array of data to the data method
2. You are stuffing non-numeric data into width and height attributes.

First, check out lines 23 and 39:

```
bar_chart.selectAll("line")
        .data(x.ticks(10))
```

and

```
bar_chart.selectAll("text")
        .data(function(d) { return d.metric1; })
```

You're not supplying data to the selection. You're providing a callback to handle a data point, but there is no data yet bound.

The data method accepts an array of data elements you want to graph. You should be doing:
bar_chart.selectAll("text")
        .data(data) // supply the passed in data array

and then use the callbacks for the individual data points.

Also, you seem to be defining some funky stuff for your rectangle widths. You go:

```
 var x = d3.scale.linear()
      .domain([0, d3.max(function(d, i) { return d.metric1; } )])
      .range([0, 420]);  
      console.log("x: " + x[1]);
    var y = d3.scale.ordinal()
      .domain(function(d) { return d.metric1; })
      .rangeBands([0, 120]);  

    bar_chart.selectAll("line")
        .data(x.ticks(10))
      .enter().append("line")
        .attr("x1", x)
        .attr("x2", x)
        .attr("y1", 0)
        .attr("y2", 120)
        .style("stroke", "#ccc");

    bar_chart.selectAll("rect")
        .data(data)
      .enter().append("rect")
        .attr("y", y)
        .attr("width", x)
        .attr("height", y.rangeBand());
```

You're specifying objects for the widths and heights of your rectangle elements. These should just be numbers.

You might want to just try to create the graph with hardcoded data first, and then make a pass supplying your data programmatically.

That's probably a good start for now.

Comment: So do I need to select just the metric1 values out of the json object that is set in .data(data)? Because the values are not passed as an array.

Comment: Try providing the whole module_1_data array as the data. Then the individual element callbacks (e.g: attr('y', function(d, i) { ... }) can act on one of the individual elements in the array.

Comment: You might want to go through a few of these tutorials just to wrap your head around the primary conventions https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Tutorials